# Meteor (React) : Access Local Package component in Meteor App

Tags: meteor, package, meteor-react

Migrating from blaze to react.I have written one **Local Package** in meteor-react. And added it in my project using command "*meteor add package_name*" successfully. I wants to use(in router/call components in jsx) the package components which are define in local package. In blaze it was easy one has to just write template name *{{> template_name}}*. But in react I have no idea about it. How to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you exported the react component from your local package like e.g. in `/packages/your_local_package_name/index.js` you wrote `export { ComponentName } from './theFileYouDefinedItIn.js';` then it's as easy as writing:

```
import { ComponentName } from 'meteor/your_meteor_username:your_local_package_name';
```

But it really depends on how you exported the component. These might be helpful resources: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#meteor-structure and https://docs.meteor.com/api/packagejs.html

Comment: OK. Tried this =>  import { ComponentName } from 'meteor/your_meteor_username:your_local_package_name'; But didn't worked . I guess need to peep into exporting method. Thank you.

Comment: You do realize that you have to substitute e.g. `ComponentName` with the actual name of your component?